# React ref attribute using callback attaches a DOM node to my class

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am currently using strings for `ref=` in React 15.3.2, and such is deprecated.

So if I use a callback per the docs:

```
ref={(input) => this.textInput = input}
```

Then this will attach a **DOM Element** to my class when the component mounts.

Yay! A DOM element. So now I do not have to do:

```
ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.refs.input).value=''; // uncontrolled component
```

I thought the whole idea of react is to not touch the DOM...

Lets assume I have a TextInput component that is complex, and has an InputError component along with `<input type="text"` -- this TextInput component does a bit of validation based on props, and it has a state that helps things like when to show error.

Back up in the form, I want to clear the form, so TextInput has a `.clear()` which resets its state. (Am I doing it wrong already?)

The thing is, I cannot access any child components **React Objects** unless I use strings as `ref=`, so I cannot call `clear()`.

What gives?

Am I supposed to route "all communication" through props? What good is `this.refs` once all refs are callbacks? Can I get my react objects through `.children` or something? What is the convention on this issue?

Edit:

Obviously I am learning React, I guess the basic question is, is it bad (anti-react) to EVER call methods on a child component?

The components in question can be found here:

[RegisterForm.jsx](https://bitbucket.org/mindprism/keyprism3/src/d4a5bfbc5a1a791bce68b172bf50c773b4f95ff4/app/imports/ui/components/RegisterForm/RegisterForm.jsx?at=master&fileviewer=file-view-default)
[TextInput.jsx](https://bitbucket.org/mindprism/keyprism3/src/d4a5bfbc5a1a791bce68b172bf50c773b4f95ff4/app/imports/ui/components/TextInput/TextInput.jsx?at=master&fileviewer=file-view-default)
[InputError.jsx](https://bitbucket.org/mindprism/keyprism3/src/d4a5bfbc5a1a791bce68b172bf50c773b4f95ff4/app/imports/ui/components/InputError/InputError.jsx?at=master&fileviewer=file-view-default)

The requirement I find difficult/strange making work via props is TextInput: "onblur then if error then show error, mark as errored until changing passes validate"

Comment: excuse me, I may not understand your question, but why don't you use controlled components? If your input is invalid, just call input.onChange('')? Also, what is clear()? Can you reference this method so I can read about it?

Comment: @leo I did an edit to the post, it now has links to the components. Can you answer the (anti-react) question? Thanks

Comment: Any pattern taken to an extreme is bad, however I think it's always possible to handle all your logic in one place and keep your forms purely presentational (via passing props, no refs at all) as things can be done by inspecting the event object on input events.